# Python - Sending email with CSV attachment

Tags: python, csv, email, dictionary

I have a script that creates a CSV file to later use to send in an email.  I am running into issues opening the file as read-only to then send as an attachment.  Below is my current code.

```
#Below code creates the CSV file
keys = lstMaster[0].keys()

with open('myfile.csv' , 'w') as outputFile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outputFile, keys)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(lstMaster)

def createEmail(outputFile)
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = 'CSV report'
    msg['From'] = "email@domain.com"
    msg['To'] = (["me@domain.com"])
    msg.preamble = 'Attachment' 

    with open(outputFile, newline='') as file:
        attachment = csv.DictReader(file)

    attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', `enter code here`filename='myfile.csv')
    msg.attach(attachment)
```

I am not getting any error messages but the code dies when trying to open the CSV file within the createEmail function "with open(outputFile, newline='') as file:"
.

Comment: did you try it in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see errors ?

Comment: if you don't get error message then how do you know that it dies in this line ?

Comment: you created function `createEmail` but you don't execute it

Comment: Sorry I left out the some of the code to keep it "cleaner".  I am calling the function.  The way I determine where it breaks is by adding print statements between lines stating "Starting email creation" , "opening attachment" , etc.

Comment: One thing to add is I wasn't seeing an error because I was using a try/except clause but not defining/printing "Exception as x:"

Answer (score 0):

It ended up that instead of calling outputFile in the "read" statement, I needed to call the file name itself.

```
with open(outputFile, newline='') as file:
```

changed to:

```
with open('filename', 'r') as file:
```

Comment: or maybe you should use this name in `createEmail('filename')`